# My DataTable becomes stuck when navigating between the table pages

Tags: javascript, datatable

I'm using server-side processing with DataTables to handle a substantial dataset. However, I'm encountering an issue specifically when navigating backward through the pages. Strangely, when I click the "Next" button, the table behaves correctly and displays the subsequent rows.

Yet, upon clicking the "Previous" button, although the data object loads in the network tab of the browser, the table remains stuck with the `Processing...` message displayed atop it. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue while utilizing the DataTables library? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

I should be able to click `previous` and see the data on the previous page displayed

Comment: We need more info (and some code would be nice). Are there any console errors? Being stuck on `Processing...` seems to suggest so, that's why I'm asking. Also, does this happen only with a large dataset? Does it always happen on the same page? Are you sure that some of the data is not malformed and breaking the returned JSON? What is your DT table size (number of rows displayed per DT page)?